# How to make nav black and transparent

Tags: html, css

How can I make the navigation black & transparent/see through like this?

[image]

I tried using rgba, but it made the black a whiter color

```css
nav {
width:100%;
height: 3rem;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav</nav>
```

Comment: "It made the black a whiter color", because the object beneath the transparent layer is pure white. If the background is particularly light, you will want a transparency value closer to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hex code

```
nav {
width:100%;
height: 3rem;
background-color: #0000009E;
}
```

Also you can try and add another css rule.. `opacity: 0.3;`
play with the value between 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're already doing it actually. You're using an rgba color value, which is already a step in the right direction.

> RGBA color value is specified with: rgba(red, green, blue, alpha). The
> alpha parameter is a number between 0.0 (fully transparent) and 1.0
> (fully opaque).

Now you just need to set your background image. Try this:

```css
nav {
    width:100%;
    height: 3rem;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  }

  nav > p {
    color: white;
  }

  body {
    background-image: url("https://webneel.com/daily/sites/default/files/images/daily/10-2013/3-nature-photography-cherry-tree.jpg");
  }
```

```html
<nav><p>Nav</p></nav>
```